# Error: 400: Bad Request: IMAGE_PROCESS_FAILED

Tags: javascript, axios, bots, telegram

I having an issue then trying to return an image from telegram's API, my terminal shows the following error:

[Terminal error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kai6x.png)

and here is the code I've writte until now...

[My code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ws6ki.png)

Comment: possibly related - https://github.com/ableev/Zabbix-in-Telegram/issues/190

Comment: yes, I worked, could you please add as an answer so I can mark it as a solution and close the post?